# How can I get a systemd service to finish before running a new service?

Tags: systemd, services

I want a service before systemd runs fstab and generates `*.mount` files to use, and some services that autostart on bootup that require that specific service to complete. Is there a way to have systemd wait for that service to finish before running a new service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a service B require a service A (e.g. by putting `RequiredBy=`serviceB.service in the `[Install]` section of service A), where service A is a `Type=oneshot` service.

In this case systemd will wait for the main process of service A (specified by `ExecStart=` in service A unit file) to complete before it starts service B.

(Not sure though if I understand correctly the first part of your question. Maybe this isn't what you were asking)