# How to make sure bash script completes before systemd service has been started?

Tags: systemd

I want a bash script to **complete** its work (not just start) before a certain `systemd` service, the solution to which AFAIK involves finishing before its *own* service has finished.

Web search finds questions about how to start. As I understand `Before=` option is to wait until unit had been started. Therefore reading `man systemd.service` I see only one option: `Type=forking`:

> the service manager will consider the unit started              when the parent process exits.

even as I do not fork any processes in a script. Am I correct here? Will that guarantee (apart from bugs, etc.) that my script will complete before service in `Before=` is started?

E.g. other type: `Type=exec`:

"while exec will not proceed before both fork() and execve() in the service process succeeded."

Unclear to me what `proceed` here means, also reading `man execve` I do not understand how systemd will know if `execve` succeed as:

> execve()  does not return on success, and the text, initialized data,
> uninitialized data (bss), and stack of
> the calling process are overwritten according to the contents of the newly loaded program.

Other types (notify, dbus) as I see from `man` need special capabilities from the process started.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a systemd service to finish before running a new service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538796/how-can-i-get-a-systemd-service-to-finish-before-running-a-new-service)

Comment: @FelixJN, no. Completing a unit does not mean completing a process in `ExecStart=` per se (and for `Type=simple` it is expressely stated in `man` page as I see it ("simple services will report success even if the service's
               binary cannot be invoked successfully"). Hence I noted only for "forking" something close to what I need is stated explicitly, but would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are fine using `type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=true`; from [the documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, **the service manager will consider the unit up after the main process exits**. It will then start follow-up units. `RemainAfterExit=` is particularly useful for this type of service. `Type=oneshot` is the implied default if neither `Type=` nor `ExecStart=` are specified. Note that if this option is used without `RemainAfterExit=` the service will never enter "active" unit state, but directly transition from "activating" to "deactivating" or "dead" since no process is configured that shall run continuously. In particular this means that after a service of this type ran (and which has `RemainAfterExit=` not set) it will not show up as started afterwards, but as dead.

It may not be fully clear, what the *main process* is, but looking at the explanation for `ExecStart=` one finds:

> Unless `Type=forking` is set, the process started via this command line will be considered the main process of the daemon.

---

**EDIT**

Note that `Type=oneshot` is the only kind that allows for multiple `ExecStart=` options. They are executed in one after the other in the order they appear, and each of them is the respective main process while it runs.

See the manuals again:

> ExecStart=
>
> Commands that are executed when this service is started. The value is split into zero or more command lines according to the rules described in the section "Command Lines" below.
>
> **Unless Type= is oneshot, exactly one command must be given. When Type=oneshot is used, zero or more commands may be specified.** Commands may be specified by providing multiple command lines in the same directive, or alternatively, this directive may be specified more than once with the same effect. If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this option will have no effect. If no ExecStart= is specified, then the service must have RemainAfterExit=yes and at least one ExecStop= line set. (Services lacking both ExecStart= and ExecStop= are not valid.)
>
> **If more than one command is specified, the commands are invoked sequentially in the order they appear in the unit file.** If one of the commands fails (and is not prefixed with "-"), other lines are not executed, and the unit is considered failed.

Comment: Seems corrent, though for Oneshot there could be several main processes that way, so does " the unit up after the main process exits" mean 1st of main processes or alfter all of them? I actually initially understood that part (though I suspect I'm wrong as word "unit" is used) as next ExecStart is started after previous exits.

Comment: @AlexMartian see updates in answer. This case is described very well. Each command is executed one after the other, the unit only consiedered active/up if all commands succeed, and the command series is aborted in case any command fails.

Comment: Thank you. I'm starting to see it is likely Ok given all the context of what unit, success, process etc. are. I need some time to ponder on that a bit.